# solidity 'for' question

Tags: solidity

For example in

```
Mapping(uint256 => address) public testForAddr;
```

It stores about 10,000,000 contents.

```
testForAddr[1] = 1
testForAddr[2] = 2
testForAddr[100] = 100
testForAddr[50100] = 6012
testForAddr[...] = ...
testForAddr[100000000] = 73159
```

If I get a key number now, such as testForAddr[7318], how can I quickly determine the value of the two keys closest to 7318 on the left and right?

e.g. I try like this:

```
for(uint256 ii = numberCount; ii < numberCount + 100000000; ii++)
{
     //numberCount == 100000000

     if(testForAddr[ii] != 0){
       //do something
       break;
     }
}
```

when I running this function, will be get this error:

```
Gas estimation failed
```

Comment: You can't enumerate the keys of a mapping. I guess you could build a linked list and traverse that? But if you explained your use case, perhaps someone can suggest a better data structure.

Comment: As for your code, it makes no sense. `ii` is initialized to `numberCount`, so `ii < numberCount` is immediately false, so the loop will never execute.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do that.

The impractical loop has to go. This is simply not feasible. In fact, you need to aim for O(1) so transaction cost (computational complexity) is scale-invariant.

From your question, it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. There is an implication of sorted data. The first thing I would suggest is working hard to eliminate that concern entirely. Have a look here for some ideas: https://blog.b9lab.com/the-joy-of-minimalism-in-smart-contract-design-2303010c8b09

Here is more explanation about why the `for` loop is a bad idea: https://blog.b9lab.com/getting-loopy-with-solidity-1d51794622ad

If the sort concern can't be eliminated then you will go to great pains to organize systems of pointers so that all operations complete in a single move. The `mapping` presented is inadequate for this purpose. You'll have to structure the data so the functions execute efficiently. These things are generally doable but not necessarily trivial.

Hope it helps.